# how to enable cookies in Gatling like jmeter

Tags: gatling

we can enable cookies by adding HTTP cookie manager in jmeter. Whats the equal way to enable cookies in gatling .can some give it with an example please.am i need to enable it on every get and post requests ?

Below shows my code sample.

```
.exec(http("request_3")
            .post("/ebscmetadata/SCMetadata.ajax")
            .headers(headers_23)
            .formParam("objType", "29958")
            .formParam("ajax_command", "data_loadProds")
            .formParam("withSelect", "true"))
.pause(200 milliseconds)
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [Gatling's documentation](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.6/http/http_helpers.html#dealing-with-cookies), cookies are automatically handled by Gatling, you have nothing special to do to have your cookies stored and sent on subsequent requests.

Comment: Yep. With Gatling, that's the opposite: you have to change the default behavior if you want to disable cookie support.

Comment: Ok guys ,tx a lot..But above mentioned script was recorded by gatling recorder when i'm trying to play back above script fails.Login to the application was successful . but next step (Above script) fails.any idea ??

Comment: @lahiruW I'm facing the same issue now. I know this is a really old thread, but do you remember what you did to resolve this?